# Vaadin save theme

Tags: java, vaadin

In app i want give possibility of change theme, but if I refresh page it is going back to default theme i don't know how to save theme for all app, someone can help me ?

```
import com.vaadin.ui.ComboBox;
import com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent;


public class ThemeSelectorComboBox extends CustomComponent
{
    private static final String SELECT_THEME = "Select theme:";
    private final ComboBox<CustomTheme> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

public ThemeSelectorComboBox()
{
    init();
}

private void init()
{
    comboBox.setCaption(SELECT_THEME);
    comboBox.setItems(CustomTheme.values());
    comboBox.setSelectedItem(CustomTheme.MATERIAL_DARK);
    comboBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> flipTheme(event.getValue()));
    setCompositionRoot(comboBox);

    // Set the size as undefined at all levels
    comboBox.setSizeUndefined();
    setSizeUndefined();
}

private void flipTheme(CustomTheme theme)
{
    if (theme != null)
    {
        getCompositionRoot().getUI().setTheme(theme.getThemeName());


    }
}
```

}

Comment: The code here looks ok, and maybe the problem is somewhere else. Which Vaadin version are you using?

Comment: Vaadin = '8.3.3'

Comment: @PreserveOnRefresh?

Comment: it dosen't  work ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Vaadin executes the UI.init on browser reload which resets the theme. You have basically two options:

1. Store the selected theme in a class variable and also call [setTheme](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#setTheme-java.lang.String-) in your [UI.init()](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#init-com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest-) if this variable has been set.
2. Use [@PreserveOnRefresh](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/annotations/PreserveOnRefresh.html) annotation to UI class to automatically maintain the the full UI state. When using this annotation this case the UI.init only called once on session start.

Comment: And if this has to "persist" even more, you can store the selected theme as a cookie or in the user data.

Comment: Could u look at next answer it still doesn't work now my theme don't want to change